# Unit of Measure for Battery Level Percentage

Tags: java, android, units-of-measurement, batterylevel

I'm using [JSR 363 Reference Implementation](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-ri) in a project.  I wish to use and display the Battery Level obtained from a Device.

Which [Quantity](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-api/tree/master/src/main/java/javax/measure/quantity) could be used to represent battery level as a percentage. Although [ElectricPotential](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-api/blob/master/src/main/java/javax/measure/quantity/ElectricPotential.java) is the obvious candidate, the devices I'm targeting report the value in a relative range from empty to full.  See [iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/batteryLevel) for example.

I plan to display it as a percentage, ideally using the [QuantityFormat](https://github.com/unitsofmeasurement/unit-ri/blob/master/src/main/java/tec/units/ri/format/QuantityFormat.java) in the general manner of handling other Quantities.

> Battery Level: 57%

The alternate display is likely graphical which I wouldn't expect the library to provide:

[image: battery levels]
<sub>(source: [freeiconbox.com](http://freeiconbox.com/icon/256/23237.png))</sub>

Comment: Electric Potential is really *not* a useful measure - it's an easy one to take, but only maps back to capacity in a non-linear fashion through knowledge of a particular chemistry's discharge curve.  Why exactly do you not want to display a percentage?  Nothing you do will be better than the merely best-estimate accurate data you are starting with anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Java ME 8 Embedded offers an optional package for [power management](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/opt-pkgs/api/meep/api/javax/microedition/power/package-summary.html), depending on your target devices, they may not run MEEP 8 or Java ME 8 Embedded. Fortunately, JSR 363 supports both, and we'll provide something similar on top of MEEP 8 and our Ri, too.

The actual class will change a bit since we're restructuring the quantities coming with the API and those in additional modules, but currently in the *SI* class of the RI, a *Dimensionless* unit constant *PERCENT*

```
/**
 * A dimensionless unit accepted for use with SI units (standard name <code>%</code>).
 */
public static final Unit<Dimensionless> PERCENT
```

is going to be available and the best unit for this use case.

Regards,
Werner Keil
Co-Spec Lead, JSR 363

Comment: It was recently added to a more general unit system called **Units** in the RI and its Java SE 8+ port. We modularized other unit systems, so "Full SI" (in API and RI we include ~30 of the most common quantities, including 22 with distinct names by SI) or others like "UCUM", "ISO 80000", etc. can be added as extension modules.